# Rolling Average Home and Away

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to calculate the rolling average in previous Home + Away matches.
With this code I can calculate previous matches in Home but I have no idea to calculate both Home and Away

```
teams = df['HomeTeam'].unique().tolist()
print(teams)
for team in teams:
    df1 = df[(df['HomeTeam'] == team) | (df['AwayTeam'] == team)]

    if (df1.loc[df['HomeTeam'] == team]).bool:
        df1['Win'] = df1['HG'] > df1['AG']

    elif team in df1['AwayTeam']:
        df1['Win'] = df1['HG'] < df['AG']
```

OUTPUT

```
                Datetime          HomeTeam          AwayTeam  HG  AG FT     1     X     2       sum
306  2020-01-24 22:30:00           Everton  U. De Concepcion   2   1  H  1.76  3.45  4.52       NaN
305  2020-01-25 01:00:00         O'Higgins   Union La Calera   1   2  A  2.24  3.17  3.10       NaN
304  2020-01-25 16:00:00       Antofagasta          Coquimbo   2   1  H  2.19  3.20  3.16       NaN
303  2020-01-26 00:30:00       A. Italiano          Cobresal   4   1  H  2.12  3.31  3.23       NaN
302  2020-01-26 16:00:00      S. Wanderers       U. Catolica   0   3  A  3.75  3.23  1.97       NaN
..                   ...               ...               ...  ..  .. ..   ...   ...   ...       ...
4    2021-02-14 22:00:00         O'Higgins         Colo Colo   1   1  D  2.27  3.14  3.10  0.250000
3    2021-02-14 22:00:00         La Serena       A. Italiano   0   2  A  2.14  3.22  3.31  0.375000
2    2021-02-14 22:00:00  Deportes Iquique      S. Wanderers   2   0  H  3.13  3.55  2.08  0.312500
1    2021-02-15 14:30:00          Cobresal       U. Espanola   4   1  H  1.29  5.59  7.67  0.500000
0    2021-02-17 22:00:00         Colo Colo  U. De Concepcion   1   0  H  2.53  3.01  2.80  0.352941
```

Example of Dataframe of a team where I want to groupby and get rolling average

```
Datetime          HomeTeam          AwayTeam  HG  AG FT
0   2020-01-29 00:30:00         Colo Colo         Palestino   3   0  H
1   2020-02-02 16:00:00          Cobresal         Colo Colo   2   1  H
2   2020-02-09 22:00:00       A. Italiano         Colo Colo   2   1  H
3   2020-02-16 22:00:00         Colo Colo       U. Catolica   0   2  A
4   2020-02-24 22:00:00      Curico Unido         Colo Colo   1   0  H
5   2020-02-29 22:00:00         Colo Colo  U. De Concepcion   2   2  D
6   2020-03-07 16:00:00         La Serena         Colo Colo   1   2  A
7   2020-08-29 19:30:00         Colo Colo      S. Wanderers   2   3  A
8   2020-09-06 19:00:00       U. De Chile         Colo Colo   1   1  D
9   2020-09-09 21:00:00         Colo Colo         O'Higgins   0   1  A
10  2020-09-12 23:30:00   Union La Calera         Colo Colo   0   0  D
11  2020-10-03 23:30:00         Colo Colo        Huachipato   0   1  A
12  2020-10-09 23:00:00          Coquimbo         Colo Colo   2   2  D
13  2020-10-14 23:30:00         Colo Colo       U. Espanola   3   5  A
14  2020-10-28 20:00:00           Everton         Colo Colo   1   1  D
15  2020-10-31 15:00:00         Colo Colo  Deportes Iquique   0   2  A
16  2020-11-10 15:00:00         Colo Colo       Antofagasta   1   0  H
17  2020-11-14 15:00:00         Palestino         Colo Colo   3   1  H
18  2020-11-19 22:30:00         Colo Colo       A. Italiano   1   0  H
19  2020-11-25 22:00:00         Colo Colo      Curico Unido   0   2  A
20  2020-12-05 21:00:00        Huachipato         Colo Colo   2   2  D
21  2020-12-08 22:30:00         Colo Colo         La Serena   0   2  A
22  2020-12-12 22:00:00       U. Espanola         Colo Colo   1   2  A
23  2020-12-19 22:00:00       U. Catolica         Colo Colo   0   0  D
24  2021-01-03 14:30:00       Antofagasta         Colo Colo   0   1  A
25  2021-01-06 14:30:00      S. Wanderers         Colo Colo   3   0  H
26  2021-01-10 22:30:00         Colo Colo           Everton   1   0  H
27  2021-01-13 21:00:00  U. De Concepcion         Colo Colo   1   1  D
28  2021-01-17 22:00:00         Colo Colo       U. De Chile   0   0  D
29  2021-01-23 22:00:00         Colo Colo          Coquimbo   2   1  H
30  2021-01-31 22:30:00         Colo Colo   Union La Calera   2   1  H
31  2021-02-07 01:30:00  Deportes Iquique         Colo Colo   0   0  D
32  2021-02-11 22:30:00         Colo Colo          Cobresal   0   0  D
33  2021-02-14 22:00:00         O'Higgins         Colo Colo   1   1  D
34  2021-02-17 22:00:00         Colo Colo  U. De Concepcion   1   0  H
```

Comment: Could you please explain more in-depth what your problem is? Do you want to calculate what percentage of the last 99 games a team has won at each new game? Do you want to do this regeardless of if its a home or away game, or for both home as well as away games? Also please make sure that your code is visible without scrolling so its easier to understand the problem. See the [python styleguide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) for how to achieve this.

Comment: I put 99 but I mean from the start of the season. Yes regardless if its home or away

Comment: @NicMoetsch Sorry, post edited without scrolling

Comment: Ok great job editing the code! You are still missing one backslash at the end of the first line with a lambda function for the code to compile, as the `/` is not inside any brackets. So your goal is to create a DataFrame where in each row, there is a column containing the win percentage of the home team up to that point of the season and a column containing the win percentage of the away team?

Comment: yes exactly that it is

Comment: Ok, I don't think `groupby` is going to get you there, at least I have never used it in comparable cases. I'd go about this problem by first filtering dfs for each team to get dfs like in your last example, then I'd calculate the win percentage for each game in that new df (If your current team is `Home` then HG > AG, else HG < AG) and then finally add these percentages back into the original df. This can be done easily as the index in the temporary df is the same as the original one. I'm willing to help you get there, so if you update your post with how far you've come I'll check back in.

Comment: @NicMoetsch Thanks for the suggestion and I update the code. With the new code I can extract unique values and filter it to get the dfs like I posted. But when I am trying to get the wins I got error `KeyError: 'Win'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233175/discussion-between-jognilie-and-nic-moetsch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.iloc[]` takes your current row and operates on only that row. So for each row, we first check, whether yout current team is home or away and the we check accordingly if in that row the current team has more goals than the other team, if yes, we set the value for only that row to `True`:

```
teams = df['HomeTeam'].unique().tolist()

for team in teams:
    df1 = df[(df['HomeTeam'] == team) | (df['AwayTeam'] == team)]    
    df1['Win'] = False
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        if df1['HomeTeam'].iloc[i] == team:
            if df1['HG'].iloc[i] > df1['AG'].iloc[i]:
                df1['Win'].iloc[i] = True
        elif df1['AwayTeam'].iloc[i] == team:
            if df1['HG'].iloc[i] < df1['AG'].iloc[i]:
                df1['Win'].iloc[i] = True
    
    df1['Rolling'] = 0
    for i in range(1,len(df)):
        df1['Rolling'].iloc[i] = df1['Win'].iloc[:i].sum() / int(i)
        
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        if df1['HomeTeam'].iloc[i] == team:
            df['HomeRolling'].loc[df1.index[i]] = df1['Rolling'].iloc[i]
        elif df1['AwayTeam'].iloc[i] == team:
            df['AwayRolling'].loc[df1.index[i]] = df1['Rolling'].iloc[i]
```